# SignalR ping fails with CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cors, signalr

In my project, the `negotiate`, `connect` and `start` API calls all contain the required `access-control-allow-origin` header. However, as soon as SignalR calls the `ping` method, it throws the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend.url/signalr/signalr/ping&_=1643292246714'
from origin 'https://frontend.url' has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I already modified my Startup.cs file according to Microsoft's documentation. I the old version, I was using the `MapSignalR` method instead.

```cs
public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR. By default this will allow all origins.
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            map.RunSignalR();
        });

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    }
}
```

However, this change didn't have any effect. The CORS error still persists. Any idea what's wrong here?

I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR 2.4.2 and Microsoft.Owin.Cors 4.2.0 with .NET Framework 4.8.

I also don't understand, why it's calling /signalr/signalr in the URL.

Comment: You have to configure CORS in your client app as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was a bug in the client library I use. The solution was to update my client-side npm package `signalr-asp-net`. I still had version 1.0.0 and updated to 1.0.3. The problem is gone now.

Answer (score -1):

You should configure your CORS like ***(the order is important)***:

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.WithOrigins(YourOriginsHere)
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));
});
```

> Note: Avoid putting `*` in the origins, it is better to create an array of strings with the possible origins, ideally reading it from configuration.

Update: For .NET Framework see how to enable CORS from this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#custom-cors-policy-providers).

Comment: Does this work in .NET Framework 4.8 as well? This is not a Core application. And I don't have the `services` property

Comment: Sure, something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#custom-cors-policy-providers

Comment: Hm, that solution uses attributes and is for WebAPI calls. I can't use it with SignalR, because I cannot modify its auto-generated methods.

Comment: .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)) will allow all origins.